# PyQT quit application events

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a PyQt app which launches some Qthreads. When I click the red 'x' in the upper left corner of a Mac OS window, I override the closeEvent function and stop my workers and this is working correctly. However, when I command+Q or File>Quit the app, the close event is still called, but the Qthreads are not terminating cleanly and I get the error:

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

My guess is that there is another event happening when I command+q, which is likely terminating things before closeEvent is called. What events happen when command+q or File>Quit is triggered and what else can I override or look into?

```
class MyWindow(QMainWindow)
    ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.stop_workers()
        self.deleteLater()
        event.accept()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: `closeEvent` in MacOS is dealt/handled/fired in slightly different ways depending on how the window is actually "closed". This is a know issue for that OS, so it's important to know how you're approaching this specific case. As already suggested, you should provide a MRE as we might provide more help based on that.

Comment: [MacOS: QMenuBar as a Global Menu Bar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#qmenubar-as-a-global-menu-bar).